# How to represent, using a Venn diagram : complement of A is included in B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems easy to me to represent :

- A is included in B

and

- A is included in complement of B.

But I can't find a way to represent : complement of A is included in B.

Comment: Let $X=A\cup B$ with $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Then $(X\setminus A)\subset B$, and this can be drawn by a very simple diagram.

Comment: If $A^c\subset B$, and the universe is $X$, then $X\setminus A\subset B$, which means that $A\cup B=X$.

Comment: @Math1000 Why do you need $A\cap B=\varnothing$? We are not requiring that $X\setminus A=B$.

Comment: We aren't requiring that $X\setminus A = B$, but we aren't excluding it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, I am following [this method](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Venn-diagram) of using Venn diagrams to represent claims, i.e. where shading an area means that that area is empty.

So, for example, to represent that $A$ is in $B$, you do:

[image]

That is: by shading the area that is in $A$ but outside $B$, any $A$ that exists is forced to be in the intersection of $A$ and $B$, i.e. it has to be in $B$ as well. So: $A \subseteq B$

Likewise, to represent that $A$ is in the complement of $B$, we have to rule out anything that is in $A$ and also in $B$, i.e. we shade the intersection:

[image]

Note that any $A$ is forced outside of $N$, and inside the complement of $B$. So: $A \subseteq B^C$

OK, so now we come to your claim that the complement of $A$ is in $B$.  Well, for that you cannot have anything outside of $A$ that is also outside of $B$. So, you can draw this by shading that very area: the area outside of both $A$ and $B$:

[image]

Note that anything that is in the complement of $A$, i.e. oputside of $A$, will have to be in the area in $B$ that is outside of $A$, and hence be in $B$, period. So: $A^C \subseteq B$

Comment: This doesn't seem clear because typically the universal set is the large rectangle enclosing all other sets. In your diagram, I can see space, or points, in the universal set that are not in any other set - even though they are shaded. I seems to me like it would make more sense to simply omit the larger rectangle altogether and have a note that says something like $U=A \cup B$

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy  Right, the rectangle is U.  And by shading everything outside of $A$ and $B$ you are forcing everything in $U$ to be in $A$ or $B$ or both, i.e. $U = A \cup B$. So, no note needed. Rather, a Venn diagrammatic representation of the claim, exactly as desired by the OP. Have you used this way of using Venn diagrams to represent claims?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy What you're proposing is an _Euler diagram_ of the statement. In a Venn diagram you're not allowed to limit the figure to three regions; for two sets you must have four regions, even if one is empty. See https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/events/conf/2004/euler/eulerdiagrams.html

Comment: @DavidK Thank you that is helpful.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Here is the link I have in my post that show how to use Venn diagrams to represent claims:  https://www.britannica.com/topic/Venn-diagram  I also added Venn diagram representations of the first two claims mentioned by the OP.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Bram Thanks that is also helpful. I understand the convention now and it is actually a lot cleaner

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Cool!  Yeah, this is actually a really nice method: it is powerful in representing claims, and by combining different bits of information into the same diagram, you can also perform reasoning or check the validity of given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your confusion is that you need to know the ambient space to know what the complement of $A$ is. Suppose $A$ and $B$ both live in some bigger set $X$. The "complement of $A$" means $X\setminus A$, and the claim is that $X\setminus A\subset B$.

Pictorially, $B$ must cover all parts of $X$ which $A$ does not cover. The resulting picture won't really look like a Venn diagram per se, but you could, for example, draw the set $X\setminus A$ as a circle inside of $B$.